# MySQL large requests don't work in AJAX and need LIMIT, while working in straight PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL table which can contain up to 500 000 rows and I am calling them on my site without any LIMIT clause; when I do it this without AJAX, it works normally, but with AJAX , again without setting LIMIT, no data is returned. I checked the AJAX code and there is no mistake there. The thing is , when I write a limit, for example 45 000 , it works perfectly; but above this, ajax returns nothing.

With limit [image]

witohut the limit : 
[image]

Can this be a ajax issue because i found nothing similar on the web or something else?

EDIT

here is the sql request

```
SELECT ans.*, quest.inversion, t.wave_id, t.region_id, t.branch_id, quest.block, quest.saleschannelid, b.division, b.regionsid, quest.yes, quest.no FROM cms_vtb as ans 
LEFT JOIN cms_vtb_question as quest ON ans.question_id=quest.id 
LEFT JOIN cms_task as t ON t.id=ans.task_id
LEFT JOIN cms_wave as w ON w.id=t.wave_id 
LEFT JOIN cms_branchemployees as b ON b.id=t.branchemployees_id WHERE t.publish='1' AND t.concurent_id='' AND ans.answer<>'3' AND w.publish='1' AND quest.questhide<>1 ORDER BY t.concurent_id DESC LIMIT 44115
```

the php :

```
var url='&module=ajax_typespace1&<?=$base_url?>';
 $.ajax({
     url: 'moduls_ajax.php?'+url,
     cache: false,
     dataType:'html',   
     success: function(data)
     {
        $("#result").html(data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Show us the code of `moduls_ajax.php`.

Comment: Is there any POST data? (Params tab)

Comment: Rjdown No I use $_GET only

Comment: Could show us the code for your ajax call and the PHP code that handles it?

Comment: added the sql request and ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a server error, adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens has to do with how you format the data sent to the client. Not having seen the code of `moduls_ajax.php`, I can only suspect that you are probably assembling the query result into a variable - possibly in order to `json_encode` it properly?

But doing so may result in a huge memory allocation, whereas if you send the data piece by piece to the Web server, you may need a fraction of the memory only.

The same happens on your web page where the same query is either output straight on, or is not being encoded. In the latter case, you'll discover that when the row number grows to about two or three times the current value, **the working Web page will stop also**.

For example:

```
$result = array();
while ($tuple = $resultset->fetch()) {
    $result[] = $tuple;
}
print json_encode($result);
```

Instead - of course, it's more complicated than before -

```
// Since we know it is an array with numeric keys, the JSON
// will be of the format [ <item>, <item>,...,<item> ]
$sep = '[';
while ($tuple = $resultset->fetch()) {
    print $sep . json_encode($tuple);
    $sep = ',';
}
print ']';
```

## Pros and cons

This is about three times as expensive as a single function call, and can also yield a slightly worse compression performance (the web browser may receive the data in chunks of different size and find more difficulty in compressing them optimally; it's a matter of tenths of one percent, usually). On the other hand, in some setups the output will arrive much more quickly to the client browser and possibly prevent browser timeouts.

The memory requirements, if the tuples are all more or less of the same size, is around two to three N-ths of before - if you have one thousand rows, and needed one gigabyte to be able to process the query, now three-four megabytes ought to suffice. Of course, this also means that **the more rows, the better...** *and the less rows, the less point there is in doing this*.

## More of the same

The same approach holds for other kind of assembling (to HTML, CSV and so on).

In some cases it may be helpful to dump the data into an external temporary file and send a `Location` header to have it loaded by the browser. Sometimes it is possible (if PHP is compiled as an Apache module on a Unix system) to output the file after having deleted it, so that it's not necessary to do garbage collection on the temporary files:

```
$fp = fopen($temporary_file, 'r');
unlink($temporary_file); // The file is deleted, the handle remains valid
fpassthru($fp); // On some platforms this results in the browser being "short-circuited" to the file descriptor, so that the PHP script may terminate while output continues normally.
die();
```